# Ionic UI Router Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have created this simple Ionic app. Just try to learn how UI router works.

However, when I was running it, nothing came up. Also, nothing shows in the developer tools in Google Chrome.

index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-    scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>


  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">
    <!--
      The nav bar that will be updated as we navigate between views.
    -->
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <!--
      The views will be rendered in the <ion-nav-view> directive below
      Templates are in the /templates folder (but you could also
      have templates inline in this html file if you'd like).
    -->
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>


  </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic']);
app.config(function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('index',  {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
    })

    .state('music', {
        url: '/music',
        templateUrl: 'templates/music.html'
    });
});
```

templates/home.html

```
    <script id="home" type="text/ng-template">
<!--        The title of the ion-view will be shown on the navbar-->
        <ion-view view-title="Home">
            <ion-content ng-controller="HomeCtrl">

<!--                The the content of the page -->
                <a href="#/music">Go to music page!</a>
            </ion-content>
        </ion-view>
    </script>
```

templates/music.html

```
    <script id="home" type="text/ng-template">
<!--        The title of the ion-view will be shown on the navbar-->
        <ion-view view-title="Home">
            <ion-content ng-controller="HomeCtrl">

<!--                The the content of the page -->
                <a href="#/music">Go to music page!</a>
            </ion-content>
        </ion-view>
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: After looking at your github repo, your app.js does not call run().

Here is something that works, in app.js define your controllers and states.
As you see I named my view as main.

```
app.controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope) {
})

app.controller('MusicCtrl', function ($scope) {
})

app.config(function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('index',  {
        url: '/',
        views: {
          'main': {
            templateUrl:  'templates/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeCtrl'
          }
        }
    })

    .state('music', {
        url: '/music',
        views: {
          'main': {
            templateUrl:  'templates/music.html',
            controller: 'MusicCtrl'
          }
        }
    });
});
```

in index.html, I named the view:

```
<ion-nav-view name="main"></ion-nav-view>
```

hom.html

```
<!--        The title of the ion-view will be shown on the navbar-->
        <ion-view view-title="Home">
            <ion-content>

<!--                The the content of the page -->
                <a href="#/music">Go to music page!</a>
            </ion-content>
        </ion-view>
```

music.html is similar.

Please note that for a real project I would not define controllers and states in app.js, I would have 3 files per page: state, controller and template inside a dedicated folder.

Comment: Hi, still not working. Btw, why do you make this change, adding name="main" to ion-nav-view?

Comment: Because I like my states to clearly define the views they manage.

Comment: I can't help you more unless you share your whole project, for instance you did not say how  and where you defined your controllers. Try sharing using codepen or github.

Comment: Hi, Gael. I have push the source code to github https://github.com/liuamy840/ionicRoute.git. Would you like to check it for me? Thank you so much.

Comment: your app.js does not call run()

Answer (score 0):

If home.html and music.html are really in separate files then you don't need to wrap them in the `<script>` tag.  That's where I'd start.

Comment: Yes. I have deleted script tag. The music.html is <ion-view view-title="Music">
</ion-view>.   But still not working